# Injecting code into an anonymous function

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

Is it possible to inject a line of code into an anonymous function body before calling it with call_user_func?

For example, say I wanted to inject this:

```
$some_var = 1;
```

into:

```
function foo()
{
    echo $some_var;
}
```

to become:

```
function foo()
{
    $some_var = 1;
    echo $some_var;
}
```

I know you can pass parameters to call_user_func but these are only available as an indexed array. I need it as a variable.

Or even being able to add a "use" to the closure before calling it would work...

EDIT:

Further example, how do popular PHP frameworks manage to do this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.domain.com'], function()
{
    echo $subdomain;
});
```

They are magically calling this anonymous function and injecting $subdomain

Comment: Seems you wanna crack something xD

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you should never have to do that. There will be a better way of achieving your goal. For the sake of answering with some actual help, you I will propose this:

```
function foo($extraAction)
{
    switch ($extraAction){
       case "action1":
           $some_var = 1;
           break;

        case "action2":
           //another action
           break;

        default:
            //do something by default

     }
    echo $some_var;
}
```

This is the closest you'll get.

Comment: Added example where this is used.

Comment: in your example, you are not seeing any new syntax. It is just a function as a parameter (in this case a callback)